# Cannot install amdgpu on Pop OS 20.04

Tags: pop-os, amdgpu

I am installing amdgpu version 21.50.1 (I need it for some programs) and constantly get this error: `E: Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.11-76051511-generic' has no installation candidate`. I tried running as sudo (same error) and I tried modding the script to use apt instead of apt-get (same error, except a red E).

The command I use is `sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation --vulkan=pro --opencl=rocr,legacy`

Comment: what version of Pop OS?

Comment: See edited title

Comment: there is "Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 21.40.1 for Ubuntu 20.04.3" , why don't you use that?

Comment: I am using that as far as I know

Comment: that link goes to a DEB file. how do you install the DEB file?

Comment: Eddy of course. Then I ran the amdgpu script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133611/discussion-between-sharuzzaman-ahmat-raslan-and-irsu85).

Comment: where is the amdgpu-install script located? /usr/bin/amdgpu-install ?

Comment: I don't remember, it was too long ago but I think it is

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `amdgpu` script to work in Pop_OS! by adding `pop` to the `case` statement that checks the Linux version in the amdgpu script.

```
case "$ID" in
ubuntu|linuxmint|debian|pop)
    PKGUPDATE="apt-get update"
    PKGMAN=apt-get
    OS_CLASS=debian
    :
;;
```